# Incorrect use of explicit keyword in c++

Tags: c++, explicit, explicit-constructor

I wanted to create a class MPSList where constructor has an explicit keyword associated with it.

Following is the bare minimal code:

```
class MPSList {                                                                           
public:                                                                                   
    explicit MPSList(int n) : n_(n) {                                                     
        mpsL.resize(n_, std::vector<MPSNode>{});                                          
        std::cout << mpsL.size() << std::endl;                                            
     }

private:
    struct MPSNode {                                                                      
        double s_;                                                                        
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<MPSNode>> mpsL;
    int n_ = -1;
};
```

CPP file that creates the object of MPSList class.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "MPSList.hpp"

int main() {
    double n = 10.9;
    MPSList mps(n);    
}
```

On compiling the above CPP file, I had expected to see an error in initializing the object. As I am passing a double whereas the constructor is explicitly expecting an int.

Command to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -I../include test.cpp 
./a.out
```

Comment: That's not what the [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) specifier is about - it only prevents [*converting constructors*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor), e.g.: in your case that would be `MPSList mps = n;`

Comment: maybe use delete keyword along your example to delete `double` and `float` versions of constructor? Idk if it would work, but give it a try!

Answer (score 6):

Explicit stops the compiler from doing something like this:

```
void fn(MPSNode x); // or void fn(const MPSNode& x)
fn(3.0);
```

The above snippet would compile if you didn't use `explicit`, and the line that calls `fn` is equivalent to:

```
fn(MPSNode(3.0));
```

This is an *implicit conversion* from `double` to `MPSNode`. Narrowing conversions have relatively little to do with it.

However, you will find that the following will not compile:

```
MPSList mps{n};
```

Use uniform initialisation syntax if you want to catch problems like that.